# IPhone: COCOS2d: Detecting touch for Sprite Animation

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a cat animation which walks and moves from one point to other.
I need to detect if the cat has been touch.
How do i do this?

I know how to detect touch if single sprite is touched.

Comment: Please elaborate.

You say you know how to detect touch, what is the problem? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Add all the spirtes to an array and check if there is any touch to one of those sprites